# Clang not generating debug info on -g flag

Tags: c++, c, windows, clang, llvm

When using clang v8.0.0 on Windows ([from llvm prebuilt binaries](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html#8.0.0)) with `-g` or `-gline-tables-only` source map tables are not being picked up by gdb or lldb debuggers.

Upon including `-g` flag file grows in size (which is to be expected) yet neither gdb nor lldb pickes the source up

When compiled with gcc though (with `-g` flag) source files are detected by debugger.

I have tried running the same command (`clang -g <codefile>`) on macOS High Sierra (`clang -v` says it is `Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000/10.44.4)`) where there source files are being picked up by lldb. So I guessed it is localized to my windows instance or llvm for windows build.

P.S. output of `clang -v` on windows:

```
clang version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
```

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you need to compile with `g++` or supply arguments to tell the compiler that you are using C++.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sorry for not being clear, but i did used appropriate (`g++` and `clang++` respectively) yet result is the same

Comment: To use the `gdb` and/or `lldb`, and be able to display the source files, those source files must be 'visible' when the debugger is running.  The easiest way is to have the executable and the source in the same directory.  I.E. the source is NOT embedded in the executable.  The executable (when compiled with the `-g` flag) does embed info about line numbers, etc. but not the actual source code

Comment: But in that case the same source file compiled with g++ (into the same output file) should result in a same behavior, yet gcc compiled one works fine with debuggers. And yes, both files (source and executable) are in the same directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Windows, Clang is not self-sufficient (at least not the official binaries). You need to have either GCC or MSVC installed for it to function.

As `Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` indicates, by default your Clang is operating in some kind of MSVC-compatible mode. From what I gathered, it means using the standard library and other libraries provided by your MSVC installation, and presumably generating debug info in some MSVC-specific format.

Add `--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` to build in GCC-compatible mode. (If you're building for 32 bits rather than 64, replace `x86_64` with `i686`). This will make Clang use headers & libraries provided by your GCC installation, and debug info should be generated in a GCC-compatible way. I'm able to debug resulting binaries with MSYS2's GDB (and that's also where my GCC installation comes from).

If you only have GCC installed and not MSVC, you still must use this flag.

How do I know this is the right `--target`? This is what MSYS2's Clang uses, and I assume they know what they're doing. If you don't want to type this flag every time, you can replace the official Clang with MSYS2's one, but I'm not sure if it's the best idea.
<sub>(I think they used to provide some patches to increase compatibility with MinGW, but now the official binaries work equally well, except for the need to specify the target. Also, last time I checked their binary distribution was several GB larger, due to their inability to get dynamic linking to work. Also some of the versions they provided were prone to crashing. All those problems come from them building their Clang with MinGW, which Clang doesn't seem to support very well out of the box. In their defence, they're actively maintaining their distribution, and I think they even ship libc++ for Windows, which the official distribution doesn't do.)</sub>