# How to get debugging symbols when compiling with clang on Windows

Tags: c, windows, clang, lldb

I am having trouble getting the debugger to work properly when setting up clang on my Windows 10 machine. Compilation seems to work OK, at least for the simple "hello, world" program I tried. However, when I try to run the lldb or gdb debuggers on this test program (or any other program I tried), it does not recognize function names.

Here's my C program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing too spectacular here, I know. I'm compiling with the following command:

```
> clang -g -O0 hello.c -o hello.exe
```

I then try to run the debugger:

```
> lldb hello
(lldb) target create "hello"
Current executable set to 'hello' (x86_64).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
(lldb) r
Process 12156 launched: 'C:\Users\********\Projects\clang-test\hello.exe' (x86_64)
Process 12156 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
(lldb)
```

Apparently the symbol "main" was not recognized, and the program did not halt at the start of the "main" function but ran to completion (in a different console window, hence no program output here).

How do I get debugging symbols to work? In a different stackoverflow answer I found that adding compiler options "-g -O0" should do the trick, but as you can see that does not solve the problem for me. I also found a different stackoverflow answer about how to set up debugging if the code is not in the same directory as the executable, but that is not relevant to my case: the current working directory is the same as the directory with the code and executable in them.

Some version information:

```
> clang --version
clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin

> lldb --version
lldb version 9.0.0
```

Comment: regarding: `lldb hello`  I suspect that should be: `lldb hello.exe`

Comment: The posted code for `hello.c` will cause the compiler to output two warnings messages about unused parameters for the statement: `int main(int argc, char **argv) {`  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: @user3629249: Invoking lldb with hello.exe instead of hello makes no difference. You could have seen from what I posted that this was the case: Process 12156 launched: 'C:\Users\********\Projects\clang-test\HELLO.EXE' (x86_64). Also, I've verified that the unused parameters in the main parameters have no bearing on lldb's behaviour. And besides, clang did not issue any warnings when I compiled my code.

Comment: There is another victim [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004739/clang-not-generating-debug-info-on-g-flag).  I haven't seen a lot of programmers being lucky with the LLVM port (well, any).  The path of least resistance is to use the clang port included with Visual Studio.

Comment: If clang did not report any problems, then you need to turn on the warnings

Answer (score 4):

The "-g -O0" options you provided should indeed let the debugger know all the symbols it needs from the executable.

Therefore, I suspect the problem is elsewhere, perhaps with your terminal, or your version/implementation of LLDB.

Are you using the windows cmd.exe commandline ? or something else, like Powershell ?
I've never managed to get debuggers working properly in those environments, but it was much easier with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which is a bash shell for windows (it creates a "simulated" linux environment within its install folder, so you have all the /usr,/bin,/etc folders a bash shell needs)
This way you can actually use `gdb` the way you would on a UNIX system.

If the above method sounds like more of a hassle than a time-gain, then yeah I would recommend another debugger altogether, like the Visual Studio debugger.
In fact, maybe a memory-analysis tool like [Dr.Memory](http://www.drmemory.org/) can give you what you need

Comment: I'm not convinced it is lldb. Gdb does not find any symbols either, nor does objdump. That said, the executable is quite a bit bigger with -g than without it, so it seems *something* is added when using -g, although it is unclear what exactly. I haven't tried the Cygwin bash shell, thanks for the suggestion: I have been running in Windows cmd. I was hoping to be able to avoid the Microsoft tooling, but you're probably right that that is the best thing to try next, in terms of time and effort needed.

Comment: maybe the gcc executable is in some format that windows has trouble recognizing ?
In fact, if you do try cygwin, try compiling with both `gcc` (which produces a linux-like executable, which needs cygwin.dll to run) and the more windows-oriented MinGW compilers: `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` (32-bit compiler) and `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` (64-bit compiler) which might give better results with your current `lldb`

Comment: I have Mingw / gcc / gdb on this computer and I was happy with the way it was working until I tried the AVX / AVX2 instruction set. Mingw / gcc aligns 256-bit AVX variables on the stack, passed as function argument, on 16 byte boundaries instead of 32 byte boundaries, leading to unpredictable segfaults. So unfortunately, Mingw / gcc is out, and that's the reason I've been trying clang. I could try Cygwin / gcc instead, maybe that version of gcc does not have the alignment issues of Mingw.

Comment: And another update: (silly that I did not think of this before): When I compile my test program with gcc (with -g option), lldb does recognize the debugging symbols.

Comment: Third update: Cygwin / gcc does not seem to suffer from the alignment issues of Mingw. So it looks like I can at least proceed with trying out the AVX stuff. Thanks for reminding me of Cygwin.

Comment: aye, well I'm glad I could be of help :) Though if ever you are to distribute the executable, remember that a cygwin gcc program needs cygwin.dll (with all the C stdlib implemented in UNIX fashion) to run, so that might not be ideal. If it's cool with you then i guess you can set the answer as accepted :) good luck with the rest