# Can I build wxwidgets with clang++?

Tags: c++, clang, wxwidgets

There are walkthroughs to build wxwidgets with common compilers on windows, such as MSVC or MinGW, but there are no options for clang. I do have the other two compilers, but I dislike using Visual Studio for projects that are not C# or other .NET languages and I just don't like [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), nothing specifically. I use [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) to compile, and I'd like to build [wxwidgets](https://wxwidgets.org) with it, but I don't know if it would error or not, so would it work? I'm using windows, if not already clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What implementation of C++ standard library do you use with Clang? There's no official binaries for libc++, so you unless you went out of you way to get it, your are either using libstdc++ from MinGW, or MSVC's standard library.

Comment: HolyBlackCat, not sure what you mean, but I downloaded all of LLVM and it seemed to work by itself, but I'd assume it's using MSVC if it isn't using it's own standard library. I'm using c++20 if that helps at all

Comment: If you didn't do anything special, then it's using MSVC's standard library, from the Visual Studio that you have installed. Since you don't care about MSVC compatibility, I would switch to MinGW's standard library (or to Clang's own libc++), because this gives you the same build process on every major OS, and lets you e.g. cross-compile from Linux to Windows.

Comment: All of that said, you can't find Clang build instructions because it mimics GCC (`clang` and `clang++` executables) **or** MSVC (`clang-cl` executable). If you decide to keep MSVC standard library, use MSVC build instructions with `clang-cl` as the compiler. Otherwise use MinGW instructions with `clang++` as the compiler.

Comment: Ah, I see. Because clang uses other standard libraries, it is essentially the MSVC compiler if you decide to use clang-cl, but with some differences with debugging and other processes. But what if I were to use libc++? Would building wxwidgets not work? I'm just curious, but I will use the GCC library to build wxwidgets, because I already use clang++.

Comment: And it seems that when you're on Windows, clang++ automatically detects it and attempts to use the MSVC library instead of the typically used library.

Comment: If you want libstdc++ (GCC's library) or libc++ (Clang's library), you can get prebuilt wxWidgets for them from [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/). From there you can also get the fresh GCC (for its fresh library) and a version of Clang that uses GCC's library by default (you can make the official Clang use it too, with a command-line flag), and also you can get Clang that uses libc++.

Comment: If you really want to build it yourself, you can take inspiration from [MSYS2 build scripts](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-wxWidgets/PKGBUILD). Note that they slightly [patch](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-wxWidgets) wxWidgets, and it may or may not build out of the box without the patches.

Comment: Every Clang version can use every standard library, only the default choice is different. The official Windows binaries default to MSVC's library. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292222/2752075) for how to switch to GCC's library, or use MSYS2 Clang binaries that do it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely build wxGTK and wxMac under Linux and Mac respectively with clang and I think people did build wxMSW under Windows with it too, but it's a less commonly used compiler there, so your best bet would be to just try doing it. If you run into any problems, please free to open tickets on [wxTrac](https://trac.wxwidgets.org/), we do want to support clang under this platform as well.